# A problem regarding the number of invariant subspaces of a vector space under a linear mapping .

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, invariant-subspace

$\mathbf {The \ Problems \ are}:$

$\mathbf {1)}$ Let, $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$ over an algebraically closed field $\mathbb F$ where $n \gt 2$. Does there exists  a linear mapping $ \operatorname T : V \to V$ such that there are exactly $k(\lt n)$ invariant subspaces of $V$ under $\operatorname T$, where $k \in \mathbb N$ ???

$\mathbf {2)}$ Let, $\operatorname T : V \to V$ be a given transformation on $V$ for $\operatorname{dim} V \lt \infty$ and let the characteristic polynomial of the corresponding matrix of transformation $A$ be $$\prod_{j=1} ^ k (\lambda-\lambda_j)^{n_j}$$ where all $\lambda_j \in \mathbb F$ and if dimension of eigenspace of each $\lambda_j \ is \ 1$, then find the number of invariant subspaces of $V \ under \ \operatorname T .$

$\mathbf {My \ approach} :$ As $\operatorname{dim} V = n$, then let an ordered bases of $V$ be $\beta = \{\beta_1, \beta_2, \cdots ,\beta_n\}$ . Now, total number of invariant subspaces of $V$ are obviously $\leq 2^n-1$ and one can always find $2^p-1$ invariant  subspaces for $p \lt n$ just by having $\operatorname T: V \to V$ such that $\operatorname T(\beta_i) = \beta_i \ \forall i \in \{1,2,\cdots,p\} 
\ and \ \operatorname T(\beta_i) = 0 \ \forall i \in \{p+1,p+2,\cdots,n\}.$

But, the stated $k$ in the question may not be always of the form $2^p-1$ for some $p$ ???

For the 2nd problem, I am completely unable to approach , any hint is appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $T$ admits a finite number of invariant subspaces IFF $T$ is cyclic, that is, $T$ satisfies the condition in 2) (when the $(\lambda_j)$ are distinct).

More precisely, if $T$ is cyclic, then, up to a change of basis, we may assume that  $T=diag(\lambda_1I_{i_1}+J_1,\cdots,\lambda_kI_{i_k}+J_k)$ where $J_j$ is a nilpotent Jordan matrix and the $(\lambda_j)$ are distinct. Then $U$ is $T$-invariant IFF $U$ is the direct sum of $\lambda_jI_{i_j}+J_j$-invariant subspaces. Thus, it suffices to find the $J$-invariant subspaces, for some $n\times n$ nilpotent Jordan block $J$.
We find the $n+1$ subspaces $\{0\},[e_1],[e_1,e_2],\cdots,F^n$.

Finally, the solution of 2) is $(n_1+1)\cdots(n_k+1)$ and the solution of 1) is NO (if $k\leq n)$ because $(n_1+1)\cdots(n_k+1)\geq n_1+\cdots+n_k+1$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer to the first question. If k=1, then obviously there IS a linear mapping with only one invariant subspace ($T(v)=0 \forall v\in V$).

Comment: @Lucio Tanzini . If $dim(\ker(T))\geq 2$, then there is an infinity (if $F$ is infinite) of invariant subspaces; if $u,v\in\ker(T)$ are independent, then consider $span(u+tv)$ where $t$ is a fixed scalar.

Comment: Yes, so what? What you have proven is that there are infinite subspaces in the kernel, not that there are infinite invariant subspaces

Comment: @Lucio Tanzini . Are you joking ? $T(u+tv)=0\in span(u+tv)$, my friend!

Comment: I see, sorry I thought that by invariant subspace we meant $T(W)=W$.